# Arduino IDE Alternatives for Mac OS X

Tags: macos, ide, arduino

I'm trying to find an alternative to the arduino text editor for obvious reasons. I can't seem to get sublime text to work with Stino (a sublime package), I think it's because I'm using arduino 1.6.4. Are there any alternatives or am I stuck with the arduino IDE? Or has anyone managed to get Stino working on sublime?

Comment: Can you tell what kind of error you get or what is not working? What have you tried?

Comment: At first I would add the arduino.app path, and then I would get an error saying it couldn't find avr-g++. Then I upgraded to sublime text 3 and used package control, and now I can't seem to add the path to the arduino.app, every time I click it just goes deeper into the ardunio.app folder.

Comment: You can also set it manually in Packages/User/Stino/Preferences.stino-settings

Answer (score 1):

Several months ago, I ran into an issue with not being able to use the Arduino IDE very well for different reasons.  I did some research and found [codebender.cc](https://codebender.cc/static/about).

Codebender works as a plugin to Chrome or Firefox, and is completely cross platform. I have used it on Windows 7,8, OSX, and on Chrome OS.

I hope you have luck with your project in whatever environment you use, Good Luck!